# Is it bad design to change the function of jButtons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm writing a small application that uses a jButton. For the sake of this question we'll call it `nextButton`. Is it bad design to change the function of the jButton throughout the programs life-cycle? Sort of like a state machine.

So say with each click of the `nextButton` the mode of my application transitions to the next "state" and the view is altered accordingly.

i.e.

```
class NextButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ServiceMode mode = model.getMode();    
        switch (mode) {
            case SELECT:
                // alter view and give nextButton function1
                ...
                model.setMode(ServiceMode.CHECK);         
            break;
            case CHECK:
                // alter view and give nextButton function2
                ...
                model.setMode(ServiceMode.COPY);    
            break;                
            case COPY:
                // alter view and give nextButton function3
                ...
                model.setMode(ServiceMode.END);                    
            break;                
            case END:
                // alter view and give nextButton function4                   
                ... 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it better to just instantiate new buttons each with their own function? Or is it better to use one button with multiple functions if possible?

Comment: Never heard about it to be a bad design. Creating buttons for hidding them doesn't look a better option.

Comment: i typically see one button with one function (set)... otherwise you will have a similar case statement in a whole bunch of places potentially.. bad

Comment: I think it's more a UI Design issue.If such a behavior is required then you can come up with a "good" software design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure the user has an idea about that would happen this time after pressing your button, I would suggest to change the button label or even icon depending on the context ([JButton.setText](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29)).

Otherwise, seems not a problem. Buttons that change, appear or disappear depending on context are common, especially in places like toolbars.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not bad design. Go along with it.